# Wrong page in table of content. two sided dokument

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, double-sided

my Nomenclature is on page 15 but it shows page 14 in the table of content. Any way of forcing the pages of table of content or any suggestions?
I am doing this in a two-sided document with open-right activated.

Please help...Thank you!

```
\newpage \renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{page}{7} 
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\input{mellom1.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
%\setcounter{page}{11} 
\listoffigures \clearpage 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
%\setcounter{page}{13} 
\listoftables 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}
```

Comment: Are you adding the ToC entry at the right place? Hard to know without seeing some code.

Comment: All of the other pages are correct except the nomenclature.

Comment: How are you adding the toc entry for the nomenclature? We don't know. Have you used `cleardoublepage` just before the toc entry?

Comment: \newpage
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table of Contents}
\setcounter{page}{7}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage


\input{mellom1.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
%\setcounter{page}{11}
\listoffigures
\clearpage


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
%\setcounter{page}{13}
\listoftables




\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}

Comment: Please edit the question to get proper code markup.

Comment: It crams the edit each time I post it. TILTED

Comment: @Anders - After copying and pasting the code block to the edit window, highlight the lines in question and click on the `{}` "button" in the ribbon above the editing window. This'll pretty-print the code.

Comment: Please also do reveal which document class you employ.

Comment: \documentclass[titlepage, twoside, a4paper, openright, english, 12pt]{report}

Comment: Have you used `\lceardoublepage` just before the toc entry? No, you did not.

Comment: before this? \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenclature}

Comment: Yes. Mind the typo just above. `\cleardoublepage`

Comment: It does not work. Now the page itself is pushed down to page 17, and in the TOC it says it is on page 15.

Comment: You have to provide a minimal working example. Just the code snippet is pretty worthless and leads us to guess what is really going on in your document.

Comment: Is there any news here?

Comment: I somewhat "fixed" the problem by not adding the nomenclature in the TOC. Thanks for the help anyway.